# MVC4 Get listboxfor Text & Value properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, html.listboxfor

In My MVC4 EF5 App i'm using 2 listboxes. each listbox is bounded to a List property of my view model.

i would like to get all listboxes items (and i mean all SelectedListItem - Selected, Text, Value) when i submit a from.

This is how i do so (with no sucess..)

My View Model:

```
public class PriorityViewModel
{

    public List<SelectListItem> lst_fromCEID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> lst_C2C { get; set; }

    public PriorityViewModel()
    {
        lst_C2C = new List<SelectListItem>();
        lst_fromCEID = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

My Action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new PriorityViewModel();

        var c2c_ceid_source = _unitOfWork.ActionRepository.GetC2C_SourceCEID();
        model.lst_fromCEID = _unitOfWork.EntityRepository.GetEntitiesByC2CSource(c2c_ceid_source);

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult UpdatePriority(PriorityViewModel model)
    {
        //save manual changes to DB
        SaveManualPriorityToDB(model);
        ...
    }
```

My View:

```
@model TRM.Models.ViewModel.PriorityViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


@*@Html.Action("Run");*@


@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdatePriority", "Priority", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Hidden("demoQuantity", Model.demoQuantity)
    @Html.Hidden("installQuantity", Model.installQuantity)
    @Html.Hidden("CIP_Quantity", Model.CIP_Quantity)
    @Html.Hidden("C2C_Quantity", Model.C2C_Quantity)
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>
                From CEID
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.lst_fromCEID, @Model.lst_fromCEID, new { width = "50px" })
            </td>

            <td style="width:50px">
                <input id="btnRemoveAllC2C" type="button" value=" << " onclick="removeallItemsC2C();" />
                <input id="btnAddAllC2C" type="button" value=" >> " onclick="addallItemsC2C();" />
                <input id="btnAddC2C" type="button" value="  > " onclick="addItemC2C();" />
                <input id="btnRemoveC2C" type="button" value="  < "  onclick="removeItemC2C();" />
            </td>

            <td style="width:50px">
                C2C
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.lst_C2C, new MultiSelectList(Model.lst_C2C), new { width = "50px" })
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2>Install & Orphan</h2>
            </td>
        </tr>


    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Run Transition!" onclick="SelectAllItems()"/>
}

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/MyScripts/PriorityScript.js"></script>
}
```

My Js File:

```
function addItemC2C() {
    $("#lst_fromCEID option:selected").appendTo("#lst_C2C");
    $("#lst_C2C option").attr("selected", false);
}

function addallItemsC2C() {
    $("#lst_fromCEID option").appendTo("#lst_C2C");
    $("#lst_C2C option").attr("selected", false);
}

function removeItemC2C() {
    $("#lst_C2C option:selected").appendTo("#lst_fromCEID");
    $("#lst_fromCEID option").attr("selected", false);
}

function removeallItemsC2C() {
    $("#lst_C2C option").appendTo("#lst_fromCEID");
    $("#lst_fromCEID option").attr("selected", false);
}
```

if i set the viewModel properties to List i can get the listbox text out on button submit. but this is not enough for me, i need Text and Value.

Thx..

Comment: the only way to get multiple fields is to build the item with jquery and send it back to the controller.  by default only one variable is passed with the post as you are seeing